# generate a loop to arrive at certain result

Tags: python, loops

I have kind of a brain fog trying to solve the following structure and maybe someone can assist in solving this issue.

```
 10 11 12 00   11 12 13 01  12 13 14 02  13 14 15 03   14 15 16 04   15 16 17 05

 10 11 12 20   11 12 13 21  12 13 14 22  13 14 15 23   14 15 16 24   15 16 17 25

 10 11 12 02   11 12 13 03  12 13 14 04  13 14 15 05   14 15 16 06   15 16 17 07

 10 11 12 22   11 12 13 23  12 13 14 24  13 14 15 25   14 15 16 26   15 16 17 27
```

How would an algorithm/set of loops look like that generates this table? The order of appearance is not important. Just all bundles of four pairs should pop up. The pairs need actually to be individual digits, i.e. a `10` is a `1` and a `0`, not a `ten`!

EDIT: there is certainly a pattern in the numbers. But I did not manage to create an appropriate loop to 'catch' the pattern.

one pattern in first row is (if only this can be solved would help already):

```
 x = 1
 i = 0
 xi  x(i+1) x(i+2) (x-1)i     x(i+1)  x(i+2) x(i+3) (x-1)(i+1) ...
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, pointing out which bit you're having trouble with?

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: Why are the last 2 groups (`16 17 18 26` and `17 18 19 27`) and not (`14 15 16 26` and `15 16 17 27`)? What sort of data structure is this table? Is it just a string, or is it supposed to be some kind of list?

Comment: @PM2Ring, amended, sorry, false copy and paste. And yes, it's a kind of list

Comment: Just out of interest, what is this for?

Comment: @TomFuller, the pairs are coordinates in a grid that I need to address.

Comment: @Al_Iskander, I see. Hopefully my answer helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code generates the desired data as a 3D list of strings.

```
a = (0, 0), (2, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2)
b = 10, 11, 12
result = [
    [
        [str(i + j) for j in b] + [str(u) + str(v+i)] for i in range(6)
    ] for u, v in a
]

# Display the resulting list in a relatively compact way    
for row in result:
    print([' '.join(u) for u in row])
```

**output**

```
['10 11 12 00', '11 12 13 01', '12 13 14 02', '13 14 15 03', '14 15 16 04', '15 16 17 05']
['10 11 12 20', '11 12 13 21', '12 13 14 22', '13 14 15 23', '14 15 16 24', '15 16 17 25']
['10 11 12 02', '11 12 13 03', '12 13 14 04', '13 14 15 05', '14 15 16 06', '15 16 17 07']
['10 11 12 22', '11 12 13 23', '12 13 14 24', '13 14 15 25', '14 15 16 26', '15 16 17 27']
```

---

If these pairs are actually supposed to be pairs of integers we need a slightly different strategy:

```
from pprint import pprint

a = (0, 0), (2, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2)
b = 10, 11, 12
result = [
    [
        [divmod(i + j, 10) for j in b] + [(u, v+i)] for i in range(6)
    ] for u, v in a
]

pprint(result)
```

**output**

```
[[[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0)],
  [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (0, 1)],
  [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (0, 2)],
  [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (0, 3)],
  [(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (0, 4)],
  [(1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (0, 5)]],
 [[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)],
  [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1)],
  [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2)],
  [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3)],
  [(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4)],
  [(1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 5)]],
 [[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)],
  [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (0, 3)],
  [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (0, 4)],
  [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (0, 5)],
  [(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (0, 6)],
  [(1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (0, 7)]],
 [[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)],
  [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)],
  [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 4)],
  [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 5)],
  [(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 6)],
  [(1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 7)]]]
```

---

Here's a variation of the 2nd solution that uses "traditional" for loops instead of nested list comprehensions. Hopefully, it's a little easier to read. :)

```
a = (0, 0), (2, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2)
b = 10, 11, 12
result = []
for u, v in a:
    row = []
    for i in range(6):
        row.append([divmod(i + j, 10) for j in b] + [(u, v+i)])
    result.append(row)
```

The built-in [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) function performs division and modulus on its arguments, so when `a` and `b` are integers `divmod(a, b)` is equivalent to `a // b, a % b`. If `x` is a two digit integer `divmod(x, 10) returns a tuple containing those 2 digits.

Comment: this result is about what I was looking for. But tbh I do not grasp the code, yet. Will need to dig into it.

Comment: @Al_Iskander I'll add a variation of the 2nd solution that uses "traditional" for loops, which may be a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with an efficient algorithm for this problem :)

```
for row in range(4):
    extra = 0
    if row >= 2:
        extra = 2
    for column in range(6):
        print(10+column, 11+column, 12+column, str(2*(row%2))+"."+str(column + extra), end = "  ")
    print()
```

Think of it like a table, you want to work through row by row, then column by column. I used the column and the row in the algorithm to determine what the numbers should be

Add a comment if there's anything you don't understand :)

Comment: Thank you. The result is in the right direction. But @PM 2Ring's answer addresses the issue with the digits more directly.